# Android: how to stop an audio started by an alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have this BroadcastReceiver:

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

var player: MediaPlayer? = null

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val message = intent?.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE") ?: return
    player = MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
    player?.isLooping = true
    player?.start()

}}
```

How can I stop the player once it got started by an alarm?

Answer (score 0):

you should create separated `Service`, which can work in background (probably you need `ForegroundService`). from your `BroadcastReceiver` you should start or notify your service for starting alarm and in `onDestroy` method of this service you should dismiss player (or with some other action)

Comment: Do you know where can I find an example on how to use such a service? Will the service drain the battery while it is waiting for the signal from the broadcastReceiver?

Comment: I've typed "foreground service" in  search engine and picked [first link, Android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). yes, theoretically it will as this is yet another construction alive, at least during playing music and keeping reference to `mediaPlayer` for further stopping. but this should be veeery small amount of power consumption, also [system may kill/"sleep" your `Service`](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) if this is really needed